# Finding extrema with Lagrange multipliers

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I'm trying to find the extrema of $f(x,y)= \cos(x^2-y^2)$ constrained to $x^2+y^2=1.$ Using Lagrange Multipliers I get this far:

$-x(\sin(2x^2-1)=\lambda x$

$-y(\sin(-2y^2+1)=\lambda y$

But I don't know how to proceed after this.

Could anyone explain to me what I have to do next please?

Comment: That looks good (apart from  sign error): now try putting $x=0$ such that the first equation is satisfied. The constraint then enforces that $y=\pm 1$ which violates the second equation. Similarly: putting $y=0$ doesn't give an extremum. Then you can assume that both $x$ and $y$ are nonzero and divide them away: you should be able to manage from there.

Comment: why does it violate the second equation?

Comment: You're right. this case cannot be excluded, but enforces a specific value for $\lambda$ in order for the second equation to be satisfied. By the way, you may want to use a parametrization $x=cos(t)$, $y=sin(t)$ which trivially satisfies the constraint. Then you differentiate $cos(x^2-y^2)=cos(cos(2t))$ with respect to $t$ to see where the extrema precisely occur and of what kind they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise not substituting in the relation $x^2+y^2=1$ yet, as you did in the equations you showed. Instead, just stick with $f_x(x,y)$ and $f_y(x,y)$. You get
$$-x\sin(x^2-y^2)=\lambda x$$
$$y\sin(x^2-y^2)=\lambda y$$
You can divide the first equation by $x$ and the second by $y$ to get
$$-\sin(x^2-y^2)=\lambda,\quad \sin(x^2-y^2)=\lambda$$
We can set the equations equal to one another:
$$-\sin(x^2-y^2)=\sin(x^2-y^2)$$
Since $\sin$ is an odd function, $-\sin(x)=\sin(-x)$. Therefore, we have
$$\sin(y^2-x^2)=-\sin(x^2-y^2)$$
From this, we have
$$y^2-x^2=x^2-y^2$$
Therefore, we can rearrange, and *then* use the relation $x^2+y^2=1$.

---

One thing, though. Dividing out $x$ and $y$ means that we assumed that $x$ and $y$ did not equal zero. This is not necessarily the case. We should test the function to see what we get for when $x=0$ and/or $y=0$< which will produce other extrema.

I thank Thibaut Demaerel for pointing this out to me.

Comment: I get that x=1/4,-1/4 and y=1/4,-1/4 does that make sense? And how can I warranty that x and y are not 0?

Comment: @darril12 It doesn't satisfy $x^2+y^2=1$, so no. But you're right that $x=\pm y$. Try $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$.

Comment: Sorry. I don't know what I did there, somehow I came to the conclusion that sqrt(1/2)=1/4. It's actually x=1/sqrt(2),-1/sqrt(2) and y=1/sqrt(2),-1/sqrt(2). Oh, I just saw that.

Comment: @darril12 Yes, I believe that's correct.

Comment: You're unjustly dividing by $x$ and $y$ in this answer and thus discarding a few extrema.

Comment: @ThibautDemaerel Which extrema does it eliminate?

Comment: Those at $(0,\pm 1)$ and $(\pm 1, 0)$. Again, try double-checking your answers by using a parametrization of the circle. e.g. $x=cos(t)$, $y=sin(t)$.

Comment: @ThibautDemaerel Both of those give you $\cos(\pm1)$, which is clearly less in magnitude than $\cos(0)$.

Comment: Sure, but we're looking for extrema, not just maxima alone.

Comment: @ThibautDemaerel Ah, you're right! I was being thick. I had been thinking that $\cos(x^2-y^2)$ could equal $-1$, and thus be a maximum, but that means that $x^2-y^2$ would have to equal $\pi$, meaning that $x\geq\pi$, thus not satisfying the constraint. Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

you have to solve
$$-2x\sin(x^2-y^2)+2\lambda x=0$$
$$2y\sin(x^2-y^2)+2\lambda y=0$$
$$x^2+y^2=1$$

Comment: Yes I know that, but I don't know how to after the step I posted. I can't find any nice way to solve it. And isn't it -2λx?

Comment: What you posted was incorrect. With answer above can you eliminate the sin term between the first two equations?

Comment: hello Paul what is incorrect?

Comment: thank you for the $-1$ but why is the question?

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner the original poster was incorrect - it was a reply to the poster (Yes, I know that...). I then suggested the poster look at your more than sufficient answer. Apologies for the confusion, I put the comment in the wrong place. Not my -1 obviously!